# Symfony router component: does annotation priority tag affect performance?

Tags: php, performance, symfony, routes

We are installing a standalone `symfony/routing` component and according to [this blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority), the routing component supports `priority` annotation property since version 5.1.

Our traffic is ~3M page views per day, so performance is relatively important.

Is it a good idea to set higher priority to most visited page routes, and lower priority to least visited pages (such as admin section)? Will there be a significant performance difference?

Comment: Priority only handles the order the routes are consumed for matching (someone correct me if I'm wrong). I think you want to group your routes using [`ChainRouter`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/components/routing/chain.html), then the prioritization is per scheme.

Comment: By default Symfony caches the routing configuration in production. Although route ordering might affect how quickly they are found I doubt that you will get a significant performance boost from ordering your routes accordingly. Only profiling will give you a definitive answer, but most likely there are other things to look at first.

Comment: priority is about routes with the _same url_. In the example in the blog post `/{some_parameter}` is the same as `/foo`. But the `/{some_parameter}` will be matched first since it is first in the list. Priority changes that and allows you to assign which is matched first. So it has **nothing** to do with most or least visited.